# Interval of convergence for square root x taylor series around x=4

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, absolute-convergence

I would really appreciate some help on this problem which I've been stuck on.
I can't seem to derive the interval of convergence of the Taylor series for square root $x$.

I know the Taylor series can be expressed as such:

\begin{align}
p(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(4)}{n!}(x - 4)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}[(2n - 3)!!](4)^\frac{1}{2}}{(2(4))^n}\dfrac{1}{n!}(x - 4)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}[(2n - 3)!!](4)^\frac{1}{2}}{(8)^n}\dfrac{1}{n!}(x - 4)^n
\end{align}

And I tried using the ratio test for convergence:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|} &= \dfrac{\dfrac{|(-1)^{n}(2n - 1)!!(2)(x - 4)^{n+1}|}{|(8)^{n+1}\cdot(n+1)!|}}{\dfrac{|(-1)^{n-1}(2n - 3)!!(2)(x - 4)^{n}|}{|(8)^{n}\cdot(n)!|}}\\
\text{which I simplified to:}\\
&= \dfrac{(2n - 2)!!}{8(n + 1)(2n - 3)!!}(x - 4)\\~\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(2n - 2)!!}{8(n + 1)(2n - 3)!!}(x - 4)
\end{align}

but I couldn't evaluate the limit :(

I don't know why I can't seem to solve this, but I know there must be a way since Wolfram Alpha says the series converges for $\mid(1-x/4)\mid<1 $

Comment: You should make it clear in your problem that you are not asking about the general Taylor series for the square root but rather the one around `4`.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.